# Как лучше реализовать категории в интернет-магазине?

Tags: php, cms

Сейчас делаю интернет-магазин на `PHP` и столкнулся с вопросом - как лучше реализовать категории, чтобы их потом можно было легко создавать из-под `CMS` (самописная) и делать бесконечно много уровней вложенности категорий, при необходимости. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основных вариантов два:

1. То, что предложил makan. Через id родительской категории.
2. Вложенный множества или Nested sets. Погуглите.

Первый вариант удобен если у вас часто добавляются записи, например, в древовидных комментариях. Тут нужно использовать рекурсию. Но не советую использовать функцию, которую предложил makan. Если будет много уровней вложенности, то будет 100500 запросов в базу данных, что не сильно хорошо. Надо одним запросом выбрать все записи, а потом уже  строить дерево.

Второй вариант, с вложенными множествами, как раз удобен в вашем случае для категорий товаров в магазине, где записи добавляются и удаляются не часто.

Если нужен пример, то можете посмотреть в CMS [TixCMS](http://tixcms.ru), там есть модуль категорий, который как раз основан на вложенных множествах.

Answer (score -1):

Создаете таблицу : id|parent_id|name, 
id - идентификатор категории, 
parent_id - идентификатор родительской категории, 
name - имя категории.

**При выводе категорий на сайте можно использовать эту функцию:**

```
function tree_cat_menu($parent_id)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m_market_categories WHERE parent_id='$parent_id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {

        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo '<ul>';
        do
        {           
            echo '
            <li><a href="?cat_id='.$myrow['id'].'">'.$myrow['name'].'</a></li>';                                
            tree_cat_menu($myrow['id']);
        }
        while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));     
        echo '</ul>';

    }
}
```

**Что касается CMS...**
Там примерно так:

```
Должна быть кнопка "Добавить основную категорию" (При добавлении этой категории parent_id = 0)
А когда в админке будете выводить список этих категории, напротив каждой категории ставьте плюсик(+ - добавить подкатегорию), соответственно при добавлении в базу parent_id = (родительская категория)
```

Попытался по короче написать... так что если что не понятно, подскажу по подробнее

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @makan, это часом не со скрипта сайта объявлений "джокер"? Там такой же ад.

Comment: @makan, где вы только находите такие решения? Значит, если будет трехуровневый каталог (что очень часто используется), то вы, только для того, чтоб составить дерево, будете делать три запроса в БД? Замечтательно... Я могу себе представить, что бы вы понаписали, если бы захотели еще и фильтры на товары каждой категории поставить.

И на кой [*цензура*] вы два раза разфетчиваете результат?

Comment: @Deonis 

> И на кой [цензура] вы два раза разфетчиваете результат?

надо одного из них поймать и спросить где они этот туториал нашли и потом либо с админом  сайта договориться, либо абузами сайт закидать.